# Passed variable reference in function not incrementing

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters

As a C++ beginner I was introduced to pointers and I'd like to know why the following program does not work properly :

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

void test(int* variable)
{
    variable++;
}


int main()
{

    int someNumber = 5;

    test(&someNumber);

    std::cout << someNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints 5 where, from my understanding, it should print 6. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Because you are incrementing the pointer, not the value it points to. Try `++*variable;` instead.

Comment: The `variable++` increments the pointer, not what the pointer points to.  Try `(*variable)++` instead.

Comment: You're not passing by reference, you're passing a pointer (by value).

Comment: You probably meant to write `(*variable)++;` incrementing the pointer does something different.

Comment: The argument `variable` is passed to `test()` by value, so modifying it has no effect that is visible to the caller.   If you want to modify `someNumber` in `main()`, you need to modify `*variable` (note the asterisk).   For example `(*variable)++`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, `(*variable)++;` and `++*variable;` work as intended but not `*variable++;` .

Comment: @Matt `*p++` is the same as `*(p++)`; it increments `p`, not `*p`.

Comment: A reference would have been preferred over a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are solutions to accomplish your task using two different methods.

```
void test(int* variable)
{
    (*variable)++;
}
void test(int& variable)
{
    variable++;
}
```

Each of these solutions will accomplish your task.
To call the second function use `test(variable)`